# Linq: Select all items group by name with count equal 0

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I have table orders(name, date, price)

```
  horse, 7.5.2012, 100
  cat, 14.5.2012, 50
  horse, 8.5.2012, 70,
  dog, 13.5.2012, 40
```

and I want to show up orders name and sum of price on Monday.
Output what I want:

```
  horse, 100
  cat, 50
  dog, 0
```

but now I have only this:

```
  horse, 100
  cat, 50
```

with this linq query

```
  from c in orders
  where (int)c.date.DayOfWeek == this._monday
  group c by c.name into g
  select new {
    Name = g.Key,
    Price = g.Sum(c => c.Price)
  }
```

Can you help me, what I must change to get output what I want, please? :)

Comment: because I want sum of all items in table. Now I have 2 horses in table, but only one is on sold on Monday, so sum of horse is only 100. If I sell both horses on Monday sum will be 170...

Comment: ok then what about line horse, 0 ? why you want that ? whats the condition for that ?

Comment: the result you want is (horse , 100, cat, 50 and DOG, 0), no ?

Comment: Wait, but you said you wanted "horse, 0"

Comment: updated; yes I want (horse , 100, cat, 50 and DOG, 0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try groupping first then do the filtering for Monday

```
from c in orders  
group c by c.name into g
  select new {
    Name = g.Key,
    Price = g.Where(c => (int)c.date.DayOfWeek == this._monday).Sum(c => c.Price)
  }
```